# Cómo inicializar log4J ? / (No appenders could be found for logger)

Tags: java, log4j

Agregué el JAR al proyecto (**Build Path**), pero aún así me da error cuando trato de invocarlo. También configuré el .properties

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (src.MiClase).
>    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

**.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, ERROR, file, toConsole

log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG

## Console output...
log4j.appender.toConsole=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.toConsole.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toConsole.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d %C (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n


## Console file.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

## local
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Tompcat\\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\\logs2018\\logBlockBuster.log

log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20000KB
# Mantiene un archivo de respaldo
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=40
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d %C (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: Deberías añadir el fichero properties a la pregunta, junto con el path del mismo

Comment: @Manuel García en que carpeta pusiste el archivo de log4j.properties

Comment: @RaulCacacho está dentro de la carpeta properties en la ruta:

Proyecto/properties/log4j.properties

Comment: @Manuel García  yo creo una carpeta dentro del proyecto le pongo en Proyecto\src\main\resources\log4j.properties  asì me funciona a mi

Comment: @RaulCacacho otras veces me funcionó en esa ruta, ahora solo cambié la ruta y reconoció el .properties. Gracias.

Comment: De nada solo agregue la respuesta por si alguien mas tiene el mismo problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tienes el archivo en una ruta incorrecta donde funciona por lo regular es `Proyecto\src\main\resources\log4j.properties`, si no tienes esas carpetas en tu proyecto, solo crealas.