# tengo un problema con la libreria de eclipse log4j

Tags: java-ee, eclipse-oxygen

Tengo un proyecto en eclipse, que guarda las variables dentro de un logger pero cuando le doy a compilar, me sale este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     The import org.apache cannot be resolved    Logger cannot be
>   resolved to a type    Logger cannot be resolved

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Puedes revisar esta pregunta tiene el mismo problema que el tuyo [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137898/c%c3%b3mo-inicializar-log4j-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger)

Comment: Según la excepción lo que **falta es importar la librería Log4j al classpath al momento de compilar tu aplicación**. Desde donde estas intentando compilar? Desde el IDE? que pasos realizas para compilar?